# how to show latency information in summary report in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How do i get the latency information to show up in the summary report table.

Currently only elapsed time average,Max,min. But it does not show latency info.

I tried by selecting "Save Latency" when clicking on Configure.

Using jmeter-plugin i am only able to generate graph for with Latency vs time. But i need to show latency in the summary report. Is there any setting i need to do.

the jtl file contains info but since it is headless not sure if latency information is showing.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you know that you can see the latency for each request in View Result Tree listener. But I guess what you want is to see an average right?

Comment: I also want to see an average. My download speed can vary from request to request so it is more consistent to measure latency

Answer (score 4):

You need to uncomment the following property in jmeter.properties file and set it to **true**

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
```

It is also possible to override the property from command line like:

```
jmeter -n -J jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true ......
```

You may also want to consider [analysis service for JMeter](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) which provides a much richer representation of load test results.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I wrote that line in both my `user.properties` & `jmeter.properties` and did a sample request but it was still measuring elapsed time instead. Pls tell me what I'm doing wrong